# How are probabilities different from expectation value for projective measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, probability, observables

For projective operators,
Suppose we have set of operators $\{P_m\}$ then according to measurement postulate, probability of getting result $m$ is (I believe $m's$ here are eigenvalue. Please correct me if I'm wrong)

\begin{equation}
p(m) = \langle\psi|P_m|\psi\rangle
\end{equation}
But this is same as expectation value of operator $P_m$. Does this mean that probability and expectation value are same for projective operators?

**Edit:**
The same is in the case of POVM. If there is a set of measurement operators $\{M_m\}$, then probability for getting result $m$ is
\begin{equation}
p(m) = \langle\psi|M_m^\dagger M_m|\psi\rangle
\end{equation}
Define $E_m = M_m^\dagger M_m$, then
\begin{equation}
p(m) = \langle\psi|E_m|\psi\rangle = \langle E_m\rangle
\end{equation}
So does  this mean probability of getting a result $m$ and expectation value of that operator is same?

Comment: A projection $P$ satisfies $P^2=P$ and can therefore only have the eigenvalues $0$ or $1\,.$ The expectation of something that can have only those values can be considered a probability.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an operator $\hat{A}$ with eigenvalues $a$. Then, in the non-degenerate case (this is easily generalized to the degenerate case), there is a set of projection operators $\hat{P}_a$ s.t. that the probability of getting the outcome $a$ upon measurement of the physical variable associated with $\hat{A}$ is
$$
p(a|\psi) = \langle\psi |\hat{P}_a | \psi\rangle\,.
$$

We can ask one of two questions:

1. "If I measure the variable associated with $\hat{A}$, what are the possible outcomes of the measurement and with what probabilities?"
2. "If I measure the variable associated with $\hat{A}$, will I get outcome $a$ or not?

The answer to the question 1 is

- $\{a\}$ and $p(a|\psi)$.

The answer to question 2 is

- We get $a$ with probability $p(a|\psi)$ and not $a$ with probability $1-p(a|\psi)$.  Put a different way, I can get the value 1 meaning "I got $a$ as the result" or I can get the value 0 meaning "I didn't get $a$ as the result." Then, 1 and 0 are the eigenvalues of $\hat{P}_a$ corresponding to the eigenvectors $|a\rangle$ and everything else, respectively.

Comment: Is there a more rigorous proof of question 2?

Comment: Rigorous proof?  What do you mean?  $\hat{P}_a$ is a Hermitian operator, and as such, it follows the standard measurement prescription, which I've outlined, and it all works because the eigenvectors of $\hat{P}_a$ are also eigenvectors of $\hat{A}$.